# Extract data from HTML to controller without using model in JAVA - freemarker

Tags: java, spring-boot, model, freemarker

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Report Preview</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Patient Data</h2>
            <form action = "reportUpdate" method = "post" >
              <input  type="text" name="fvalue" value="testingData1"/>
              <input  type="text"  name="svalue" value="testingData2"/>
              <input  type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a SpringBootProject and I'm using the above Freemarker code template file(*.ftl). I tried to display some input field with the values(binded), after editing I want to extract the data from HTML input tags(fvalue,svalue) to controller without using any model. How to get the values?

My controller code:

```
@PostMapping({ "/reportUpdate"})
    public String reportToUpdate( ) {
        
        String firstName = ""; // I should get fvalue here
        String secondName = ""; // I should get svalue here
        
        //Some other logics which will use above value.
        
        return "Data saved!";
    }
```

Comment: so far, there is no actual question in your question, nor is there actual (Java) code to look over.

Comment: @Stultuske I have added the controller code now .

Comment: Use method parameters annotated like `@RequestParam("fvalue")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `HttpServletRequest` request, `HttpServletResponse` response we can get the data from HTML form.
Using the below code.

```
public void getDataFromForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
                
     // Get the values from the request using 'getParameter'
     String name = request.getParameter("name");
                
}
```

For more info, you can see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/servlet-form-data/).